# C# Copy Files from Source with, to Target without Subfolder

Tags: c#, copy

I want to copy all Files from a source Directory incl. all Files from Subdirectories to a simple target Directory without Subdirectories.

**e.g. I have this source Dir with Files to copy:**

C:\TEMP\SOURCE\file1.txt

C:\TEMP\SOURCE\file2.txt

C:\TEMP\SOURCE\Subfolder1\file3.txt

C:\TEMP\SOURCE\Subfolder2\file4.txt

**I want to have this target Dir in result (without Subfolders):**

Normally there should be no doubled Filenames, but overwriting should be allowed if happens.
The files are 100% shure identical.

c:\TEMP\TARGET\file1.txt

c:\TEMP\TARGET\file2.txt

c:\TEMP\TARGET\file3.txt

c:\TEMP\TARGET\file4.txt

I tried the following code:
It ends in an error, because the target seems to need also the Subfolders as the source...

```cs
string sourceDIR = @"C:\TEMP\SOURCE\";
string targetDIR = @"c:\TEMP\TARGET\";

string[] arr_File_List = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDIR, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories); // Search also in all Subdirectories

foreach (string f in arr_File_List)
{
    // check sourceDIR to have a Backslash in the end
    if (!sourceDIR.EndsWith(@"\")) sourceDIR = sourceDIR + @"\";

    // Remove path from the file name.
    string fName = f.Substring(sourceDIR.Length);

    // Use the Path.Combine method to safely append the file name to the path.
    // Will overwrite if the destination file already exists.
    File.Copy(Path.Combine(sourceDIR, fName), Path.Combine(targetDIR, fName), true);
}
```

**My Error-Message is:**

Could not find a part of the path: C:\TEMP\TARGET\ **Subfolder1** \file3.txt

I dont want the Subfolder in the target ...

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Thre is `Path.GetFileName(String)`  method ... also why don't you use `f` as source parameter of `File.Copy` you've path to source already?

Comment: Whatever you want to tell me ... I did not understand it.

Comment: One approach you might take is, instead of directly copying everything from the root of the source folder, recursively iterate into directories in the source folder and copy just the files in each folder therein.  So each copy operation would be targeting just one file and specifying the target folder.

Comment: http://selvin.pl/whateveryouwant.png where is the problem?

Comment: Selvin: Thank you for your answer. I answered to this Post, so you can get also what i was trying to do ... I am shure, i did not understand what you want to tell me, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code inside of a Button, posted as Picture from Selvin.
Thank you for it.

My Code just a little down.

As i understood you right, this should do the trick.

There came up no error, but also nothing happens^^

Did you want to combine your line of code with my originally posted code?

I am sorry, i am too far away in this moment.

```
private void button_test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp\source", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(x => (x, Path.Combine(@"C:\temp\target", Path.GetFileName(x))));
}
```